# How to get canGoBack functionality in Ionic 5?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to put a back button in Ionic app and to hide the back button when it's in the root, which the root is not fixed and can be changed based on the flow. I found the following code here:

```
...
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private ionRouterOutlet: IonRouterOutlet
) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.canGoBack    = this.ionRouterOutlet.canGoBack();
...
```

It would be nice if it works but IonRouterOutlet is component and cannot be injected to another component like this. Any idea about how can it be done in Ionic 5 with angular?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@ViewChild(IonRouterOutlet, { static : true }) routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet;

    // if (this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) or whatevet...
```

Comment: What the difference if I use { static: false }?

Comment: If set to false, then it means it is dynamic and not static, and router outlet should be static since its one of angular standards in the angular project. Like ion-app is one of the standards of ionic project which holds the outlet. And dynamic means that it could be self edited by developer so it should be static.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying 'Cannot find name "ViewChild" ' if I put it inside the AppComponet class. If I put it outside, I get an error saying 'Declaration expected'

Comment: Fixed it. I needed to import ViewChild from @angular/core

Comment: In my case this `@ViewChild` solution didn't work. But injecting `private ionRouterOutlet: IonRouterOutlet` in the constructor of the page component like written in the question worked. We are using `<ion-router-outlet>` in the template of our app and then have the @ViewChild only once in the AppComponent.